# Set up GitLab CI/CD for deploying multiple repositories to Docker containers on a DigitalOcean Droplet

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, gitlab, digital-ocean

I am very new to the concept of Docker and DigitalOcean Droplets. I have created a DigitalOcean Droplet that runs Docker 19.03.12 on Ubuntu 20.04.

I currently have three repositories on GitLab:

- Two Node.js servers
- One Vue.js frontend

And I want to accomplish the following:

- Set up a CI/CD pipeline for each repository that deploys each application to a docker container on my DigitalOcean Droplet.

Here's what I am struggling with:

- What does the Dockerfile for each project contain?
- What does my GitLab CI script contain?
- Since my DigitalOcean Droplet has one public IP address, how do I deploy three seperate applications to that one IP address and still be able to reach them all? By deploying them to different port numbers?

I have tried following the tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-continuous-deployment-pipeline-with-gitlab-ci-cd-on-ubuntu-18-04, but it doesn't quite fit my requirements as it's only for one application. The tutorial also focuses on one static HTML file. In my case I need to dockerize two Node apps and one Vue app.

Sorry for the lack of information, this is the most context I am able to give with my (limited) knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two possibilities, one is to use three docker containers on your droplet that talk with one another. By the sounds of it that's what you might considering (based on *"each repository that deploys each application "* and *"What does the Dockerfile for each project contain"*)

The other option is to have a single container that holds all three repos, which I think might be a better solution for you (but there are merits for both).

The benefit is that the latter may be a bit simpler.

The idea is that none of the three repos will need a dockerfile (for deployment anyway)

Instead you create a 4th repo that just has `Dockerfile` and `.gitlab-ci.yml` files. That dockerfile will pull the three other repos and make them part of the same image, so they can run on your droplet as one container. Then, each of your other three repos will have a hook to your 4th repo, that will notify that one to generate the image.

if you need to access all three applications, you will likely need three separate ports to run on.

Note however that the vue frontend will need to be served as-well, so you may be able to use one of your servers to serve the vue app as flat files and also host the api for it.